# Giant contend 3 stem adjustments possible?

Tags: stem, giant

Looking to buy a Giant Contend 3 2022, would like to make the bike less aggressive for commuting purposes.  I went to the shop and sales person said stem height is not adjustable on this but can be rotated?  Don't remember exactly what he said.  Can you not add spacers to the stem to make it taller? or what kind of adjustment can you make to this stem, in particular, to make the handlebars higher?

Stem is "Giant Sport" on their website

[image]

Comment: Please include a photo of your bike stem, including top of the frame and bars. That will also is to provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ideal commuter bike for many reasons, the lack of stem adjustment being just one. But, if the bike is shipped as shown in the photo, the steerer tube is cut too short and there isn't any room add spacers under the stem. The options are flipping the stem so that it would be pointing up slightly more, or replacing it with a different one.

Comment: what would be some other reason for not ideal commuting ?

Comment: @Lightsout narrow tires and no clearance for wider, no options for fenders or cargo rack. It's basically an entry level race bike with all drawbacks of one.

Comment: Also, this is my personal experience and there may be different opinions, but trying to make a road bike more comfortable by raising the bars without changing anything else makes it just worse. And you can't change much else on this bike.

Answer (score 0):

While the stem cannot be adjusted it can be replaced. It looks like it clamps to a standard 1 1/4 in steerer tube and had a standard 31.8 mm bar clamp. (Check before buying!)

You can get stems in different lengths and at different angles. Many stems can be flipped, so the angle points down or up, making bar position lower or taller.

Often stems are too long and low for riders. A good bigger shop will be able to recommend and install a stem that fits you better and most importantly let you try the stem out.

If you are more serious about fit you may go to a dedicated bike fitter.